# OpenVSwitch won't install on my Alma Linux server

Tags: openvswitch, rhel8

When I am attempting to install OpenVSwitch from the RPM generated from the documentation, it spews out an error, the following. I have python2 installed, python3, and python3.6. I generally do not know why it is showing this, but my 9:40 at night brain can't exactly comprehend much.

```
[root@Alma-85-amd64-base x86_64]# yum install python2
Last metadata expiration check: 1:15:52 ago on Tue 08 Mar 2022 02:20:48 AM CET.
Package python2-2.7.18-7.module_el8.5.0+2579+77770ab7.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@Alma-85-amd64-base x86_64]# rpm -i openvswitch-2.17.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        python >= 2.7 is needed by openvswitch-2.17.0-1.el8.x86_64
[root@Alma-85-amd64-base x86_64]#
```

Comment: Are you sure that python is the same as python2? It looks like you haven't got python installed.

Comment: Whenever I run “yum install python” nothing comes up. I’ll try to add a repo with python, and I’ll let you know.

Comment: It did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's an update. I could not get OpenVSwitch to work on any version of RHEL 8, but it did work on RHEL 7.